# why is my useEffect not being called initially?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

In my functional react component, my useEffect hook is not being called on initial render and throwing error, but if i keep refreshing than it works.
I cant find the solution.

```
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

function WatchMain({ watchVideo, videos, setLoading, fetchVideoById }) {
  let query = useQuery();
  let id = query.get("v");

  const setTitle = (id) => {
    videos.forEach((video) => {
      if (video.id.videoId === id) {
        document.title = video.snippet.title;
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in use effect");
    setTitle(id);
    setLoading();
    fetchVideoById(id);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <WatchMainContainer>
      {!watchVideo ? <Loading src={loadersvg} alt="loading" /> : <VideoData />}
    </WatchMainContainer>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  watchVideo: state.videos.watchVideo,
  videos: state.videos.videos,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setLoading, fetchVideoById })(
  WatchMain
);
```

I have excluded the imports

I am using useQuery to parse the query param id.
my url looks like this http://localhost:3000/watch?v=1GQ9mH5Zzr0
the id can be seen in logs. but the useEffect is not fired.

Comment: The best way to do that is just to make a middleware component for taking care of loading data and fetch data initially.

Answer (score -2):

If you want your useEffect to trigger in the first render then dont use any dependency inside the array of useEffect ,do it like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in use effect");
    setTitle(id);
    setLoading();
    fetchVideoById(id);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Make two `useEffect`

Comment: yea that can be done,but since his concern is that useEffect should trigger on first render then this useEffect will be the solution.

Comment: Leaving the dependency array empty only means it won't run _again_.  It doesn't cause it to run the first time any more than having a dependency list does.

Comment: And he should get an error: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency`

Comment: Then using two separate useEffects should work.

Answer (score -3):

Your component is not called on initial render because you passed an "id" argument to useEffect :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [id]);
```

When you pass a variable in [ ], useEffect will trigger only when this variable changes. It is like a componentDidUpdate. Just remove it and it will trigger on every render.

Comment: An empty dependency list means it will only trigger on mount, not "only when this variable changes."

Comment: Even with a dependency, useEffect triggers the first time too.